# What is a better way to access properties of JSON object if they have names like option1, option2

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic-arrays

The configObj has many properties like `{ 'name':'test', 'option1': 'test', 'option3': 'test', 'option2': 'test', 'option4': 'test', 'other1':'blah', 'other2':'blah2' }`

I was wondering if there was a way to do something like this:

like convert this

```
optionArray[i++] = configObj.option1;
```

to this

```
optionArray[i++] = configObj.option + i;
```

FULL CODE :

```
var optionArray = new Array();
var i = 0;
if (configObj.option1 != "") {
    optionArray[i++] = configObj.option1;
}
if (configObj.option2 != "") {
    optionArray[i++] = configObj.option2;
}
if (configObj.option3 != "") {
    optionArray[i++] = configObj.option3;
}
if (configObj.option4 != "") {
    optionArray[i++] = configObj.option4;
}
```

Comment: `configObj["option"+(i++)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
var optionArray = new Array();
for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    var option = configObj["option" + i] ;
    if (option != "") {
        optionArray.push(option);
    }
}
```